# Скорочення цифрами складних числівникових прикметників в академічних та побутових текстах

Tags: прикметники, скорочення, числівники, складні-прикметники

Якщо я хочу написати "**двадцятип'ятирічного**" в академічному або побутовому (переписка) тексті використовуючи цифри, то яку форму скорочення мені краще обрати?

1. "25-ти річного";
2. "25-го";
3. "25-тирічного";
4. ваш варіант;
5. скорочення взагалі недопустиме в такому форматі.

Як правильно? Яке правило унормовує такий вжиток?